# How to programmatically obtain list of stored procedures and functions associated with an assembly

Tags: sql-server-2008, sqlclr

I started with list of all CLR stored procedure list:

```
select *
from sys.procedures
where type_desc = 'CLR_STORED_PROCEDURE'
```

But I want to obtain the list of all stored proc and functions associated with a specific assembly.

Thank you for your advice.

Comment: perhaps: sys.sql_dependencies is what you're looking for. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174402.aspx  however given removal in futre release: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677315(v=sql.105).aspx

Answer (score 1):

You can try following:

```
select * from sys.assembly_modules
```

This will list all functions and the assemblies.